# Quadratic Discriminant Analysis - understanding the algorithm

Tags: r, classification

I have some training and test data that I want to write my own QDA for (not use the existing function in R).

I'm struggling to understand the algorithm, for each of the k classes, are the mean vector and covariance matrices for each class estimated using the training data, and then plugging in each observation from the test data?

That's what I'm currently doing but am getting different prediction results when comparing with the function.